# How do I can integrate Facebook to my own app?

Tags: android, facebook

I have an app. I want to integrate Facebook to this. I want to make it because I have a program, which count numbers. I want enable the user to send its counted number to his/her user feed on Facebook. I have read the facebook's page for developers about the sdk, and about the imports, but I don't know for example, how I can make my program, that the user need to press a button, and then if he want to connect to FB , he will can. I only read about how I can build all of my program "over" FB .  And I don't know how I can enable the user, to post its number to fb if he press a button, but I only want to show this button, if the user connected to fb. Could you please give me any tutorials, helps, and advices please? Or example codes? Thank in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is to Download the Sample Code from GitHub Source ,it include the following
1. Authentication Process.
2. Logout Function from facebook.
3. Post on User Wall.
4. Upload image to user Album.

Check this [Facebook test Application](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk)

Use Test folder for getting all the above options..
Also it is Library Project follow the steps in Readme file.

For further more Info check this [Facebook for Android](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sdk)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, and answer, I will look through these in the tests folder. Thanks.

Comment: I have a problem with get my android programs hash code. I tried to go to the Java file and the to cmd and copy/pasted the line from facebook developer site (modded place because I have E drive instead C so it was E:\DaS\User\.android...), but it writes for me that it can't find openssl. Can you help me please?

Comment: Interesting... Now I could make it, I got a code, but I didn't need to write the password. I don't know, the Facebook site says, it won't be good, but I made it with the right path... Oh and thanks accepted it. If you couldn't make it yet, write it here please and I will write down how I made it.

Comment: I asked that where I can find the file which was downloaded by git, but I have found it :)

Comment: Could you get the hash key? I used the method what I founded in this site, so I didn't use the keytool, and I hope it will be great... Hope

Comment: Try out what Mina said, with this method you needn't to play with keytool.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484561/keytool-with-android-facebook-sdk