# How to create the signature Hash code for integrating facebook in an android Application?

Tags: android, android-emulator, command, android-2.2-froyo, facebook-android-sdk

I am using facebook integration in to my application. But i got stop at get Hash code of the Android application. Link to get Hash code for facebook: [Here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sample).

I am using this syntex in commend prompt but got error like keytool is not recognized as an internal or external command:

```
D:\Users\Priyadarshan\.android>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keyst
ore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Please help me in this.
Thanks.

Edited:

After seen that :[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211919/errorkeytool-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-p).

I have Done like below but still got error:

```
D:\Users\Priyadarshan>cd C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool -exportcert -ali
as androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary |
openssl base64
'openssl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

After Some guide I have done like below but still got error:

```
D:\Users\Priyadarshan>cd C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool -exportcert -ali
as androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | D:\Users\Priyadarshan\o
penssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | D:\Users\Priyadarshan\openssl-0.9
.8k_WIN32\bin\openssl base64
The system cannot find the path specified.
2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=
```

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484561/keytool-with-android-facebook-sdk

Comment: Remove the cd in your command.  You don't want to change to the directory, just give the full path to keytool.exe

Comment: @brianestey: If i remove the cd then it will say that "C:\Program" is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: That's why you need quotation marks around the full path "C:\Program Files\..."

Comment: @brianestey: Thanks Dear. I got the Answer and got Sollution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have keytool in a different directory:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin

You can either add the path where `keytool` is into your PATH environment variable, or you can use quotes around the full path like

> D:\Users\Priyadarshan.android>"C:\Program Files\etc\keytool.exe" -exportcert etc etc

Don't forget the quotation marks because of spaces in the path!

Answer (score 2):

`keytool` comes with the JDK.

You'll find it, assuming you installed the JDK with default settings, at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\keytool.exe`

Answer (score 1):

THE Coder from facebook documentation to get the hash code just run it in the emulator

```
   try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md;

                    md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                    String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                   //Toast.makeText(StartingPlace.this, something,
                        //  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("hash key", something);
        } 
        }
        catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
        }

             catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 Log.e("no such an algorithm", e1.toString());
            }
             catch (Exception e1){
                 Log.e("exception", e1.toString());
             }
        //code to get hash code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Open SSL from this [link](http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/), 
this issue is discussed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347924/key-hash-for-facebook-android-sdk)